# Getting different results Puppeteer and startsWith()

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer

I'm trying to read the links of a website using Puppeteer and filter the results using the `startsWith()` function.

The problem is that I'm getting different results depending if `startsWith()` gets a parameter as a variable, or it gets the value directly as a string.

Example:

```js
const root = 'https://tiempone.com';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(root, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

// root and string are equal -> 'https://tiempone.com'
let urlsToVisit_1  = await page.$$eval('a', links => links.map(link => link.href).filter(link => link.startsWith(root)));  
let urlsToVisit_2  = await page.$$eval('a', links => links.map(link => link.href).filter(link => link.startsWith('https://tiempone.com'))); 

console.log(urlsToVisit_1); 
// []

console.log(urlsToVisit_2);  
// ['https://tiempone.com/', 'https://tiempone.com/projects', ..., 'https://tiempone.com/privacy']
```

I expect both `urlsToVisit_1` and `urlsToVisit_2` to be equal.

Why I'm not getting the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` is declared in the Node.js context, while the function in the `page.$$eval()` is executed in the browser context. You need to transfer the variable explicitly:

```js
let urlsToVisit_1  = await page.$$eval(
  'a',
  (links, root) => links.map(link => link.href).filter(link => link.startsWith(root)),
  root,
);
```